# Create margin on Fragment with Widget

Tags: android, android-studio

This is an example of my activity with element fixed and automatic margin:

[image]

But when use fragment:
[image]

Its possibile to set margin on fragment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the fragment container in your activity xml, set padding to the container. In your specific case, set it to the ViewPager.

example:

```
android:padding="10dp"
```

Comment: Im not use xml for include fragment
 ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        adapter.addFragment(new Tab5(), "Dati");

Comment: <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:padding="10dp"

Perfect thanks so much =)

Comment: Set the padding in the ViewPager within your xml file

Comment: Nice :) I'm glad it helped. Don't forget to accept the answer as the correct one

Answer (score 0):

Try providing margin to the container you are using to contain your fragment.

for eg. if you are using the framelayout as a container give margin to the frame layout.